# Saving images with HDF5 and cPickle cost much more disk memory than just storing the same amount of image files directly in disk?

Tags: python, image-processing, pickle, hdf5, large-data

I am trying to saving a large amount of images. I want to save them in a format that costs as less disk memory as possible. I have tested with HDF5 and cPickle in python. Surprisingly, I found out that the data files generated by PyTables and cPickle have much larger sizes than the folder that contains the same amount of images.

My code is here:

```
import cv2
import copy
import cPickle as pickle
import tables
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread("aloel.jpg")
images = []
for i in xrange(1000):
    images.append(copy.deepcopy(image))
images = np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8)
hdf5_path = "img.hdf5"
filters = tables.Filters(complevel=5, complib='blosc')
with tables.open_file(hdf5_path, mode='w', filters=filters) as hdf5_file:
    data_storage = hdf5_file.create_array(hdf5_file.root, 'data', obj=images)

with open('img.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(images, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

The folder that contains 1000 copies of `aloel.jpg` consumes **61.5 MB**, but the `img.hdf5` and `img.pickle` are both **1.3GB** in size.

I wonder why this occurs?  If this is the case, does it mean that it would be better to directly save image data into individual image file rather than save them into a pickle file or hdf5 file?

Comment: BLOSC is lossless compression, so it doesn't surprise me, that the file sizes are bigger. HDF5 will always be a little bigger as it stores Meta Data information. HDF5's main advantage is storing structural Data, not always disk space.

Comment: The jpg format is already a lossy compressed file. Will be difficult to reduce their size even more, unless you're willing to lose even more information.

Comment: You could store the jpeg images as binaries, rather than writing them in as a table.

Comment: This phenomenon also occurs when I used `.png` images.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
your problem is that compression is not applied at all, because first you need to have chunking, which can be achieved by replacing "create_array" with "create_carray". Then, apply "zlib" with complevel 5 and you should see already some improvement. For this particular case, of course, it makes sense to set chunking also along the repeated data axis, so if you add something like `chunkshape=[100,100,100,3]` to the `create_carray` command, you should see a major change.

Jpeg is highly efficient lossy compression algorithm. Blosc is optimised for speed, and pickle is not compressed at all by default. There are other options for HDF5 available, take a look at https://support.hdfgroup.org/services/filters.html and I believe you can find a method that is close enough for original jpeg.

Comment: He can still use JPEG compression within the HDF5 data tree, but he is storing them as a table and BLOSC'ing them. And I don't think that you can achieve a better compression by converting an image into a table and applying a text based compression.